# How i can access components in a MatStep by typescript in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material-stepper

I need to access all components in stepper's step in typescript, i have the following:

```html
<mat-vertical-stepper #stepper (selectionChange)="ChangeSelection($event)">
  <mat-step label="Step 1">
    Step 1
  </mat-step>
  <mat-step label="Step 2">
    Step 2
    <app-comp1>  </app-comp1>
    <app-comp2>  </app-comp1>
  </mat-step>
</mat-vertical-stepper>
```

Knowing that `comp1` and `comp2` implements `IComp` (custom  interface)

```js
export interface IComp {
  MethodeFromInterface?: { (data?: any): void }; //this is optional
}

export class Comp1 implements IComp {
  MethodeFromInterface(data: any) {
    //do something here
  }
}

export class Comp2 implements IComp {
  MethodeFromInterface(data: any) {
    //do something here
  }
}
```

the main component has

```js
ChangeSelection(event) {
  var m = (<IComp>event.selectedStep);
  if (m.MethodeFromInterface.InnerComponents[0]) // InnerComponents is an example  
    m.MethodeFromInterface("TEST");     
}
```

so is there is anything like innerComponents inside  MatStep ?

Comment: Why exactly do you require access to all components within the steps? If it's for validation, you could use the `stepControl` attribute on each step

Comment: the content that should load on the next step depends on the input of the previous step
i will use the method to pass parameters an load content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment, it sounds like you want to dynamically change the stepper content, based on the previous step. I would use an event-based approach for this, rather than a imperative approach.

A solution could be to send events out of the step components into the parent component. Then let the parent render the appropriate changes.

Parent HTML

```html
<mat-vertical-stepper #stepper (selectionChange)="ChangeSelection($event)">
  <mat-step label="Step 1">
    Step 1
    <app-comp0 (stateChanged)="step1State.next($event)">  </app-comp0>
  </mat-step>
  <mat-step label="Step 2">
    Step 2
    <app-comp1 [step1State]="step1State | async">  </app-comp1>
    <app-comp2 [step1State]="step1State | async">  </app-comp1>
  </mat-step>
</mat-vertical-stepper>
```

Parent Typescript

```js
step1State = new EventEmitter();
```

Child Typescript `app-comp0`

```js
@Output()
stateChanged = new EventEmitter();
```

Child Typescript `app-comp1`

```js
@Input()
set step1State(newState) {
  // Do work here
}
```

Now `Step 2` components depend on the state of the `Step 1` component. You could continue this, linking different components based on many `@Input`'s and `@Output`'s of each component.

This also makes it easier to reason about, as each component only depends on the events given, rather than a direct dependency.